# How to find 3 digits and only 3 digits using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to search all files for the string `111` and only that. Strings as #111 or 13211123 should not be found.

I tried:

```
grep -rE "1{3}" .
```

But this is not what I need, I really need to find only 111 nothing in front of it and nothing behind.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use `grep '^111$' .`. `grep -E "^1{3}$" .`  will work, too.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Anchoring